# let win10 show desktop or recent windows instead of start menu after log in

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

When you log in to Windows 10 after awaking from enery saving mode, then Windows 10 will present the start menu dialog (the dialog behind the WIN-Key) and this will hide all recent windows.

How can we instead set up Windows 10 to *not* show the start menu but only the recent window(s)?

Clearly, this can be achieved by pressing ESC when the menu is shown, but we explicitly do not want to see the overlay anyway since customers run in tablet mode without a keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

In the settings > system > tablet mode

Change the "when I connect" option to desktop mode

The name of the options may be a little different my system is not in English

Comment: thank you. this works, as long as I do not activate the energy saving mode via the start menu. in that case, the start menu still is present after reactivation.